# three.js load object/model and then manipulate sub-parts/children

Tags: javascript, model, 3d, load, three.js

I have a 3D model of a robot arm, that I want displayed and manipulated in the browser.

My question is: how do I load the model into three.js, so that I can manipulate all sub-parts of the robot arm.

As an example I have a rotary motor and a shaft attached as an assembly in Inventor.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/custz.png

This is exported as an stl file and imported in Three.js using STLLoader.js.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLmBe.png

I want to know how I can manipulate the shaft to turn to a specified angle.

I have loaded the model using the following code:

```
<div id="container"></div>

    <script src="three.js\build\three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js\STLLoader.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Set size variables
        var SIZE_x = 400, SIZE_y = 400;

        // Set three main THREE variables
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, SIZE_x/SIZE_y, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        // Set renderer options
        renderer.setSize(SIZE_x, SIZE_y);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
        renderer.clear();

        // Append to HTML Dom
        //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        $('#container').append(renderer.domElement);

        // Create light
        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
        pointLight.position.x = 10;
        pointLight.position.y = 50;
        pointLight.position.z = 130;            
        scene.add(pointLight);

        // Move camera
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 20;
        camera.position.z = 20;



        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
            var geometry = event.content;

            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { ambient: 0xff5533, color: 0xff5533 } );
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            scene.add( mesh );

            mesh.traverse(function ( child ) {
                //if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    console.log("Hej: " + child);
                //}
            });
            //scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry ) );
            console.log('Loaded');
        } );
        loader.load( 'models/AssemblySimple1.stl' );

        // Render loop
        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);

            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
    </script>
```

Any points and hints are welcome. Also if there is a preferred export file format. I have both SolidWorks and Inventor at my disposal. Or if I've taken a completely wrong approach to the problem, please let me know of other ways.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure out something reasonable to do here for interacting with assemblies?  I still haven't seen a really good 3D model tool for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Three js has function called THREE.STLLoader() .This one can be used to load stl file.
 Here is the way how it is loaded

```
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        var group = new THREE.Object3D();
    loader.load("../lib/SolidFz.stl", function (geometry) {
        console.log(geometry);
        var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x7777ff});
        group = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
        group.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
        group.scale.set(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
        scene.add(group);
    });
```

Here scene

```
 var scene new THREE.Scene();
```

After that you have a created 3d object and loaded one added into that 3d object.Then you can control that 3d object as you wish. According to this way  you can load several parts and do the what you want to do with that